# Angular barcode scanning with a device

Tags: angular, barcode-scanner

I am trying to implement barcode scanning with angular, I am using @zxing/ngx-scanner already but the performance is slow, and I cannot get it to work with a scanner device. It is only working with my PC camera.

Please, I would like to know if there is any sdk to use with angular and would be compatible with a scanner device that I can buy form a store or something.

Thanks.

Comment: A typical barcode scanner will actually type numbers/letters as if it was a keyboard... it is very much compatible with every webpage, you only have to detect it.

Comment: I am having same issue, did you got any solution for same?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue with slow performance on [ngx-scanner](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner). I would suggest using version 3.0.0.

On my phone, it scans in the blink of an eye.

Still having issues with the iPad as it is very slow on it. I will try to find a solution to that.